# A variation on the subset relation with an underlying squiggle

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a variation on the `\subseteq` relation, but with an underlying squiggle instead of a line. In other words, I'm looking for the symbol to substitute for the square in the last printed line of following example.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\prec + \sim &= \precsim\\
< + \sim &= \lesssim\\
\subset + \sim &= \square
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: A variation on the subset symbol with an underlying squiggle]

I couldn't find any matching symbol using [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/).

Comment: `stix` has `\subsetapprox` but with 2 squiggles.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: This would work, except I get a `LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.` when I try to use the package `stix` in my actual document (not the sample one listed in my post above).

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Upon further inspection, it appears there are three packages in my preamble that clash with `stix`, namely `mathrsfs`, `stmaryrd`, and `unicode-math` (I should note that I use the `lualatex` format with the `scrbook` document class). The first two packages produce the error message listed in my previous comment, whereas the third package produces the error message `Command '\mathbfit' already defined.` Is there a way to resolve these errors, so I can use `stix`'s `\subsetapprox` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `stix` package gives you some incompatibilities, you can define your own symbol, without any additional package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\subsetsim}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\raise.4ex\hbox{$\subset$}\cr$\raise-.9ex\hbox{$\sim$}$}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\prec + \sim &= \precsim\\
< + \sim &= \lesssim\\
\subset + \sim &= \subsetsim
\end{align*}
\[ \precsim \lesssim \subsetsim \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you! Is there a way to lower the squiggle a little bit, so the vertical space between the subset symbol and the squiggle resembles that used in `\precsim` and `\lesssim`?

Comment: @EvanAad Of course, instead of `\raise-.8ex` you can put a bigger value. I'm modifying.

Comment: @EvanAad See my renewed answer. You can also furtherly refine...

Comment: @EvanAad See campa's answer, it's better than mine.

Comment: `\ooalign`? Oh, no!

Comment: @egreg what's wrong with `\ooalign`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX You don't want to superimpose symbols, but just to stack them. The right function is either `\ialign` or `\oalign`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb, accents} %
\newcommand{\subsetsim}{\mathrel{\underaccent{\mkern6mu\sim}{{\subset}}}}
\newcommand{\supsetsim}{\mathrel{\underaccent{\backsim\mkern2mu}{{\supset}}}}%{\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{-1ex}{\sim}{\subset}}}

\begin{document}

 $ E \subsetsim F \iff F \supsetsim E$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The places the “subset” part at the same height as in `\subseteq`. Other choices are possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\subsetsim}{\supsub@setsim\subset}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\supsetsim}{\supsub@setsim\supset}

\newcommand{\supsub@setsim}[1]{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\supsub@setsim@{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\supsub@setsim@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\subseteq$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\z@-\height}{%
    \vbox{\offinterlineskip
      \ialign{%
        ##\cr
        $\m@th#1#2$\cr
        \noalign{\vskip0.6pt}
        \hidewidth$\m@th#1\sim$\hidewidth\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\subseteq B \subseteq C$

$A\subseteq B \subsetsim C \precsim D$

$\scriptstyle A\subseteq B \subsetsim C$

\end{document}
```

[image]